# spring data jpa CrudRepository findone sometimes return null

Tags: spring-data-jpa

My question description:

1 my userDao  has two method one calls repository.saveAndFlush, the other calls repository.findone then update  record , these two methods are called in different transactions, when first transaction is finished then start to 
run methd 2, but sometimes the method 2 repository.findone return null.

2 environment: mysql ,springdatajpa use hibernate

3 can anyone give me some solutions,  many thanks..

Comment: We need more information to help you. Show the code of the methods and how/when they are called.

Answer (score 1):

in my case I had a similar incidence, I use jhipster:

"generator-jhipster": "4.6.0",
Hiberante 5.2.8.Final.

It happened to me that after saving and reloading the edit view, for example http: // localhost / entity / {id} I got EntityNotFoundException, I thought it was due to some configuration of hibernate with its second level cache, but after reviewing my entity I realized that I had this:

```
@ManyToOne (optional = false)
     private Order originOrder;

@ManyToOne (optional = false)
     private WhareHouse deliveryLocation;
```

When originOrder and deliveryLocation could be null, then change them as my business model should be:

```
@ManyToOne (optional = true)
     private Order originOrder;

@ManyToOne (optional = true)
     private WhareHouse deliveryLocation;
```

And what do you think? That was all, it had taken me more than 2 weeks reading and looking for references to this weird error, I hope and this could help you, if that is the case

Comment: Had exactly the same situation: enforcing a not nullable on a foreign reference to a second entity if the relative column is effectively nullable leads the items to be filtered out because jpa translates this reference into an inner join rather than an outer join when creating the query